# performance of vmware-machine on different computers

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm working on a filesystem improving project, and found a paper says the cheating on benchmark, and it gives a solution that use VMs could help others to reproduce our result.

And the question is, if I have made a specific vmware virtual machine, will it runs the same at different computer and platform?

For example, I have a virtual machine which is 1G RAM, 4G HD and 2G one-core CPU.

Will that runs the same at a qual-core 3G CPU and a 2.4G P4?

What if the computer have 4G RAM? Will vmware use some buffer mechanism to improve performance? If that's true, does it means the VM runs on a 2G RAM host will slower than on a 4G host?

Hope you can help me on that, or just told me where could I find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get different results. VMware workstation (and ESX if ECM isn't turned on) will pass through all of the processor benefits of the host machine. If one is a 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2, and another is a 2.4GHz Intel I5, the I5-based machine will perform a bit differently for certain workloads than the same VM running on a Core2 system.

RAM *performance* will also pass through, though not quantity since that's restricted by the VM configuration.

Comment: Is there any configure file could limit that? I mean try to disable some feature and make this VM runs the same at different computer?

Comment: @bxshi Not that I'm aware of. ESX has the option in the Enhanced Compatibility Mode, but I don't believe Workstation does.